What is the most efficient way to figure out if a single number is prime for numbers from 2 up to 2,147,483,647 in Java?
As Java programmers, we can always use the BigInteger isProbablePrime() method or store manually all prime numbers in a HashMap. This question is about the most efficient way to figure out if a single number is prime for numbers from 2 up to 2,147,483,647 in Java using Data structures and custom Algorithms.
I was thinking the most efficient way to do this would be to return a result quickly if number is small or even and only then examine the odd prime values. In my research partly generating prime numbers using Sieve of Eratosthenes up to the square root should then be the most efficient way to proceed. By simple search right now I also found that also Sieve of Sundaram or Sieve of Atkin could be used instead, but I am unsure if Integer.MAX_VALUE is within the range to be efficient asymptotically.
Is there a more efficient way to generate primes than this, I wonder? (see code below)
public static boolean PrimeTime(int num) {
  if(num < 4) {
    return true;
  }
  if(num % 2 == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  int max = (int) Math.sqrt(num);
  boolean[] notPrimes = new boolean[max];
  if(8 < max) {
    int findMax = (int) Math.sqrt(notPrimes.length);
    for(int odd = 3; odd <= findMax; odd = odd + 2) {
      if(!notPrimes[odd - 1]) {
        for(int i = odd * 3 - 1; i < notPrimes.length; i = i + 2 * odd) {
          notPrimes[i] = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  for(int i = 2; i < notPrimes.length; i = i + 2) {
    if(!notPrimes[i]) {
      if(num % (i + 1) == 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}

I compared boolean[] to BitSet after tip from David Conrad. My benchmarks (with blackhole and state) showed higher throughput for boolean[] (40 % more) searching for the highest prime number Integer.MAX_VALUE with 8218,042 ± 735,978 ops/s for boolean[] and 5729,806 ± 271,468 ops/s for BitSet.

This is a topic that has been (and is still) studied a lot. You already mentioned the sieve of Atkin, and there are several other ideas for improvements.

See also Finding prime numbers with the Sieve of Eratosthenes, Improving efficiency of Sieve of Eratosthenes code in java, Improving a prime sieve algorithm, Sieve of Atkin - Explanation and Java example. I'm not convinced this needs yet another question.

A BitSet would certainly be more efficient than a boolean[].

"... but I am unsure if Integer.MAX_VALUE is within the range to be efficient asymptotically." - You should be able to test that for yourself.  (And for the record, the practical way to do this "as efficiently as possible" is to simply read a bitmap representation of the set of all primes from a file.  "Amortize" the computational and developer cost of actually generating the primes.  Or see if someone has generated such a file already.)

Generation of primes on Wikipedia

@DavidConrad So? Did you measure? A BitSet would require a lot of bit operations to retrieve and set single bits, which a boolean array avoids. Or did you mean space efficient? With 2 thousand million entries that would seem to matter.

About BitSet versus boolean[] which depends on max: one could also try byte[] as boolean reserves 4 bytes. Maybe primes merits a sparse bitset implementation. But the alogrithms are more interesting

@Anonymous I did indeed mean space efficient.

The title of your question does not correspond to what your code is doing. That code doesn't return a list of primes, but checks whether the given number is prime or not. Those are different problems and an efficient solution for them is different. Please focus your question on what exactly you need.

The answer is in Matt Timmermans' comments. Use Miller-Rabin tests.

Just factor it. Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267146/what-is-the-fastest-integer-factorization-algorithm/2274520#2274520 the best method in this size range is from https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~brent/pub/pub051.html. In Python, primefac implements it. Just googling randomly, https://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-pollard-rho-algorithm/ looks like an implementation in Java.

Efficient for one single number not known in advance? Or for a whole lot of them?

The fastest way to prove primality for integers (2 up to 2,147,483,647) in Java is to do a strong probable-prime base a (an a-SPRP) using 2, 7 and 61 as a base. "A test based on these results is quite fast, especially when combined with trial division by the first few primes".(https://t5k.org/prove/prove2_3.html)
I constructed such a SPRP-test with 2, 7 and 61 as a base using fast trial division by 2 with bit manipulation after checking if n was equal to a-SPRP or not.
import java.math.BigInteger;

class Main {

  public static final BigInteger ONE = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
  public static final BigInteger TWO = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
  public static final int[] INTEGERS_SPRP = {2, 7, 61};

  public static boolean PrimeTime(int num) {
    if(num < 4) {
      return num >= 2;
    }
    if(num == INTEGERS_SPRP[1] || num == INTEGERS_SPRP[2]) {
      return true;
    }
    if((num & 1) == 0) {
      return false;
    }
    return passesMillerRabinStrongProbablePrimeBaseForIntegers
      (new BigInteger(num + ""));
  }

  private static boolean passesMillerRabinStrongProbablePrimeBaseForIntegers
    (BigInteger biUnderTest) {
      // Find a and m such that m is odd and biUT == 1 + 2**a * m
      BigInteger biUTMinusOne = biUnderTest.subtract(ONE);
      BigInteger m = biUTMinusOne;
      int a = m.getLowestSetBit();
      m = m.shiftRight(a);

      // Do the tests
      for (int i = 0; i < INTEGERS_SPRP.length; i++) {
        int j = 0;
        BigInteger z = new BigInteger(INTEGERS_SPRP[i] + "")
          .modPow(m, biUnderTest);
        while (!((j == 0 && z.equals(ONE)) || z.equals(biUTMinusOne))) {
          if (j > 0 && z.equals(ONE) || ++j == a)
            return false;
          z = z.modPow(TWO, biUnderTest);
        }
      }
      return true;
  }

}

To prove that this functions is true for all integers I then genererated a txt-file containing all positive integer prime numbers using the following code:
import java.util.*;

public class Prime {

  private static final Map<Integer, Integer> next = new LinkedHashMap<>();

  public static boolean[] generatePrimes(int maxValue) {
    boolean[] primes = new boolean[maxValue];
    Arrays.fill(primes, true);
    primes[0] = false;
    primes[1] = false;
    int findMax = (int) Math.sqrt(maxValue);
    for(int i = 2; i <= findMax; i++) {
      if(primes[i]) {
        int j = i * i;
        while(j < maxValue) {
          primes[j] = false;
          j = j + i;
        }
        next.put(i, j);
      }
    }
    return primes;
  }

  public static boolean[] generatePrimes(boolean[] oldPrimes, int time) {
    boolean[] newPrimes = new boolean[oldPrimes.length];
    Arrays.fill(newPrimes, true);
    int maxValue = time * oldPrimes.length;
    System.out.println(maxValue);
    int findMax = (int) Math.sqrt(maxValue);
    for(int i = 2; i <= findMax; i++) {
      if(oldPrimes[i]) {
        int j = next.getOrDefault(i, i * i);
        while(j < maxValue) {
          newPrimes[j - (time - 1) * oldPrimes.length] = false;
          j = j + i;
        }
        next.put(i, j);
      }
    }
    return newPrimes;
  }

  public static int[] generatePrimes(int from, int to) {
    int[] primes = new int[(to - from) + 1];
    int i = from;
    for (; i < to; i++) {
      if (isPrime(i)) {
        primes[i - from] = i;
      }
    }
    return primes;
  }

  public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
      return false;
    }
    if (n == 2) {
      return true;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++) {
      if (n % i == 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;

  }
}


import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Instant start = java.time.Instant.now();
    Main.printPrimes();
    Instant end = java.time.Instant.now();
    Duration between = java.time.Duration.between(start, end);
    System.out.println( between ); // PT2H21M8.2257144S
    System.out.format("%dD, %02d:%02d:%02d.%04d \n", between.toDays(),
        between.toHours(), between.toMinutes(), between.getSeconds(), between.toMillis()); // 0D, 02:141:8468.8468225
  }

  private static void printPrimes() throws IOException {
    Path file = Paths.get("src/main/resources/primes.txt");
    int timeMax = 214, batchSize = 10_000_000;
    List<String> lines;

    boolean[] primes = Prime.generatePrimes(batchSize);
    lines = new ArrayList<>(1_000_000);
    for(int i = 0; i < primes.length; i++) {
      if(primes[i]) {
        lines.add(String.valueOf(i));
      }
    }
    Files.write(file, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    int time = 2;
    for(; time <= timeMax; time++) {
      boolean[] newPrimes = Prime.generatePrimes(primes, time);
      lines = new ArrayList<>(1_000_000);
      for(int i = (time - 1) * primes.length; i < time * primes.length; i++) {
        if(newPrimes[i - (time - 1) * primes.length]) {
          lines.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }
      }
      Files.write(file, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    }

    int[] lastPrimes = Prime.generatePrimes(timeMax * batchSize, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    lines = Arrays.stream(lastPrimes).filter(v -> v > 0)
        .mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
    lines.add(String.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    Files.write(file, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
  }

}

Integer.MAX_VALUE is a known prime so was simple added to the list to prevent overflow. Then I just created a Java Nio File stream and checked that all match true when running the SPRP-method. After that I did a test checking if all non-primes return false.
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

public class PrimeValidatorTest {

  @Test void allIntegersPrimesReturnTrue() throws IOException {
    Path file = Paths.get("src/main/resources/primes.txt");
    boolean allNumbersArePrimes;
    try(var stream = Files.lines(file)) {
      allNumbersArePrimes = stream
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .allMatch(Main::PrimeTime);
    }
    assertTrue(allNumbersArePrimes);
  }

  @Disabled //Warning: Took 56 minutes to run it on my computer 
  @Test void allIntegersNonPrimesReturnFalse() throws IOException {
    Path file = Paths.get("src/main/resources/primes.txt");
    int[] primes;
    try(var stream = Files.lines(file)) {
      primes = stream.mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
    }
    for(int i = 0, primeI = 0; primeI < primes.length; i++, primeI++) {
      while(i < primes[primeI]) {
        if(Main.PrimeTime(i)) {
          System.out.println(i);
          fail();
        }
        i++;
      }
    }
  }

}

After that I created benchmarks using only Integer.MAX_VALUE for comparison. I was comparing the performance with the probalistic method isProbablePrime() using certainty 40 performing 20 random Miller-Rabin tests giving a certainty of 99.9999999 % compared to 100 % for SPRP and optimized version of the question.
The optimized version of the algorithm in the question (code at the end) increased the speed (50 %) 14822,264 ± 639,563 ops/s than the algorithm in the question 10133,307 ± 448,365 ops/s, but had half the throughput compared to isProbablyPrime(). The deterministic SPRP method was even faster than isProbablyPrime() creating 8.5 times as much throughput so the code at the top is probably preferable for performance.
Below is the optimized version of the algorithm which also return correct values for n=1 and uses bit manipulation to increase the speed for even positive values ((num & 1) == 0) and odd numbers in the for loop (i = i + odd << 1). The speed comes from excluding numbers divisable by two and three when we just need to check if numbers 6*k +-1 with k = 1 ... sqrt(n) are prime.
public static boolean PrimeTime(int num) {
  if(num < 4) {
    return num >= 2;
  }
  if((num & 1) == 0 || num % 3 == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  int max = (int) Math.sqrt(num);
  boolean[] notPrimes = new boolean[max];
  int lowestPrime = 5;
  if(lowestPrime * lowestPrime <= max) {
    int findMax = (int) Math.sqrt(notPrimes.length);
    for(int odd = lowestPrime; odd <= findMax; odd = odd + 2) {
      if(!notPrimes[odd - 1]) {
        for(int i = odd * odd - 1; i < notPrimes.length; i = i + odd << 1) {
          notPrimes[i] = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  for(int i = lowestPrime; i <= notPrimes.length; i = i + 6) {
    if(!notPrimes[i - 1]) {
      if(num % i == 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    if(i + 1 < notPrimes.length && !notPrimes[i + 1]) {
      if(num % (i + 2) == 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}


Looking at this answer and your question and comments, I'm unsure what an "op" is, but ops per second is the wrong benchmark. The important metric is time to completion, and this will be a function of num, the number to be tested. Your code appears to be O(sqrt(num)), and thus will be slowest for the largest values of num. And it should be compared to isProbablePrime(5), not isProbablePrime(40), because a custom version of Miller-Rabin given in the link provided by Matt Timmermans uses only 5 bases to determine primality with 100% accuracy.

Your own analysis in this answer shows it is O(n^1/2). You write "...we just need to check if numbers 6*k +-1 with k = 1 ... sqrt(n) are prime...". That's O(n^1/2). I didn't say you could use isProbablePrime(5) to determine primality, I said to use a custom implementation of Miller-Rabin. The amount of time that custom implementation should be approximately the time for isProbablePrime(5) modulo a few assumptions. Read the link Matt Timmermans provided. The question is not what ops/s means, the question is what do you consider an "operation" to be.

Ok, I agree that isProbablePrime(10) does 5 MR passes and thus would be a better comparison. You could just copy the source code for passesMillerRabin() to create the custom implementation using the five bases 2, 3, 5, 7, and 11.
